# How to Launch Google TV Panoramio Android Sample in Emulator

Tags: android, google-tv

I am trying to Launch Google TV Panoramio Android Sample in Emulator.

I am using Windows XP, and using Project Build Target: Google TV Addon : Platform 3.2 (API Level - 13)

Please below Screenshot:

[image]

Console (Android)

```
[2013-06-12 14:33:41 - Panoramio] Android Launch!
[2013-06-12 14:33:41 - Panoramio] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-12 14:33:41 - Panoramio] Performing com.google.android.panoramio.ImageGrid activity launch
[2013-06-12 14:33:41 - Panoramio] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyDevice'
[2013-06-12 14:33:41 - Panoramio] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyDevice'
[2013-06-12 14:33:47 - Panoramio] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-12 14:33:47 - Panoramio] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-06-12 14:34:28 - Panoramio] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-12 14:34:28 - Panoramio] Uploading Panoramio.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-12 14:34:28 - Panoramio] Installing Panoramio.apk...
[2013-06-12 14:35:16 - Panoramio] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-06-12 14:35:16 - Panoramio] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-06-12 14:35:16 - Panoramio] Launch canceled!
```

Logcat:

```
06-12 09:09:12.542: D/dalvikvm(651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 18% free 2504K/3052K, paused 75ms+4ms, total 157ms
06-12 09:09:12.552: W/ActivityManager(287): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f65bb0
06-12 09:09:57.406: D/ExchangeService(651): Received deviceId from Email app: null
06-12 09:09:57.406: D/ExchangeService(651): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
06-12 09:10:02.451: D/ExchangeService(651): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
06-12 09:10:02.462: D/ExchangeService(651): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
06-12 09:10:02.462: W/ActivityManager(287): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-12 09:10:02.472: D/ExchangeService(651): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-12 09:10:02.481: W/ActivityManager(287): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-12 09:10:02.481: D/ExchangeService(651): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf2f70 that was originally bound here
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf2f70 that was originally bound here
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-12 09:10:02.512: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651): null
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf2f70 that was originally bound here
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-12 09:10:02.521: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 09:10:02.521: W/ActivityManager(287): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f99b88
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd2890 that was originally bound here
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd2890 that was originally bound here
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-12 09:10:02.552: E/ActivityThread(651):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651): null
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd2890 that was originally bound here
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-12 09:10:02.562: E/StrictMode(651):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 09:10:02.573: W/ActivityManager(287): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f619c8
```

Comment: We are strongly recommending folks don't use the emulator for Google TV. A device is under 100 USD. That said, I don't see mention of which library your missing in the logcat, you might need to include a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Typically with the emulator, you should only need to check Android 3.2.  Checking the Google TV AddOn doesn't do anything additional for your project.  There are no additional public apis brought in.  Do you have your project on GitHub anywhere where it could be viewed?

Make sure as well that you have the google tv emulator setup correctly.  You can use a Nexus 7 profile if you want instead of using the google tv emulator profile.

http://waynemay.com/installing-and-configuring-the-google-tv-emulator/