# Creating Google TV AVD on windows not deteecting x86 System Image

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-tv

I am trying create the AVD for Google TV on API 13 on windows machine. but while creating, it throws a error asking to install the Intel x86 System Image. but i don't find the x86 system image in the sdk manager for API 13 where as I can see it on other later APIs. (Have already installed it for other APIs)

Could some one please help me fix this and get the Google TV AVD up and running.

Comment: can you installed google tv addon on your sdk manager?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061791/how-to-launch-google-tv-panoramio-android-sample-in-emulator/17114244

Answer (score 2):

I've found workaround for this problem. Tested it on Ubuntu 12.10 but it should work for Windows and Mac OS.

Here are the steps:

1. download *Intel x86 Atom System Image for Android 2.3.3 (API 10)* using *Android SDK Manager*
2. create folder `<sdk-root>/system-images/android-13/x86`
3. copy everything from `<sdk-root>/system-images/android-10/x86` into `<sdk-root>/system-images/android-13/x86`
4. edit `<sdk-root>/system-images/android-13/x86/source.properties` file with any text editor and replace next rows:

> Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Platform **2.3.7** => Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Platform **3.2**
>
> Pkg.Revision=**2** => Pkg.Revision=**1**
>
> AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=**10** => AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=**13**

That's it. Now if you open *Android SDK Manager* you will see *Intel x86 Atom System Image for Android 3.2 (API 13)*.
Also it would resolve error message while creating AVD with *Google TV Addon (API 13)*.

I had luck to launch emulator and work with it. However there is no guarantee that you would have correct behavior using this emulator.